# How to display items from a dataframe in html SEPARATELY by django?

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

I'm using Django and I'm using the following structure for the database:

```
class Main(models.Model):

    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    main_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    changeover_time = models.FloatField()
    cycle_time = models.FloatField()
    available_time = models.FloatField()
    FPY = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = [Lower('title')]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

--

In my VIEWS I have the following code:

```
def home(request):
    item = Main.objects.all().values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=item)
    df_gb = df.groupby(['title']).agg(
        {'cycle_time': 'mean'})
    mydict = {
        "df": df_gb.to_html()
    }

    return render(request, 'teste.html', context=mydict)
```

--

In my Html Template (teste.html) I have the following code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}


{% block 'body' %}


<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">C/O: <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{df|safe}}
```

```
</ul>






{% endblock %}
```

--
The results are :

```
C/O: 

                      cycle_time
title   
Product Conference        2.0
Product Descharging       7.0
Storing                   1.0
Typing                     3.5
buying                     3.0
```

--

Displays all averages, using all data from my database, filtering by titles. it works ok

But I need to display in the html the averages SEPARATELY, not all together.

```
Something like:
C/O = 2.0
C/O = 7.0
C/O = 1.0
C/O = 3.5
C/O = 3.0
```

I've already tried using FOR and I can't display these values isolated in my HTML .

--

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}


{% block 'body' %}

{% for i in df %}
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">C/O: <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{i.title}} 
</span></li>




</ul>





{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

--
It doesn't work

Can someone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Try passing `df_gb` to the template instead of `df_gb.to_html()` .. My instinct tells me `to_html()` just spits out a string, and you need the Object

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is happening because you're passing a dataframe. You need to convert the data to a list and pass it to a dictionary. I give an example where the dataframe is converted to a list: df['time'].values.
**'bboard' replace with the folder where your template is located.**

views.py

```
import pandas as pd

def home(request):
    df_gb = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

    context = {'df': df_gb['time'].values}

    return render(request, 'bboard/rank_templ.html', context)
```

templates(rank_templ.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
{% for i in df %}
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">C/O: <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{i}}
</span></li>
</ul>

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @Ederson please check the box below the upper and lower triangles (so the answer counts).